# Swift Array Running Total to x item

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, reduce, cumulative-sum

Swift has a great function .reduce that provides a running total for an entire array:

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let addResult = array.reduce(0) { $0 + $1 }
// addResult is 15

let multiplyResult = array.reduce(1) { $0 * $1 }
// multiplyResult is 120
```

But is there a simple way to use this for a running total only up to a specific element? For example for an array of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] is there a way to use the .reduce function to return a running total for only up to the 3rd item (1+2+3=6)?

(I know I can always do a loop, just trying to learn all the possibilities with swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closure called by `reduce()` has no information about the 
current index.
Theoretically it is possible to create a closure that
uses a captured variable to "remember" how often it has been called:

```
func addFirst(var count : Int) -> (Int, Int) -> Int {
    return {
        count-- > 0 ? $0 + $1 : $0
    }
}

let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let sumOfFirstThreeItems = array.reduce(0, addFirst(3) )
```

But this would still run over the whole array and not just the
first 3 elements. There is no way to "stop" the process.

A much simpler way is to operate on an array slice:

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let sumOfFirstThreeItems = array[0 ..< 3].reduce(0) { $0 + $1 }
```

A slice is an `Array`-like type that represents a sub-sequence of any
`Array`, `ContiguousArray`, or other `Slice`.

Answer (score 2):

Besides using the `reduce` method of arrays, as in @MartinR's answer, it's also possible to use the global `reduce` function along with `enumerate`

The `enumerate` function returns a sequence of tuples, whose first element (named `index`) is the element index and the second (named `element`) is the element value.

So you can achieve the same result with the following code:

```
let sum = reduce(enumerate(array), 0) {
    $0 + ($1.index < 3 ? $1.element : 0)
}
```

The advantage of this method is that you can apply more complex rules to exclude elements - for example, to sum all elements having even index:

```
let sum = reduce(enumerate(array), 0) {
    $0 + ($1.index % 2 == 0 ? $1.element : 0)
}
```